# error while loading shared libraries: libcaffe.so

Tags: c++, caffe

I am trying to write a simple c++ application which uses caffe.

This is part of my makefile:

```
 FLAGS := -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/guinness/GamerIA/Caffe/caffe  /include/ -I/home/guinness/GamerIA/Caffe/caffe/src/ -I$(ALE)/src -I$(ALE)/src/controllers -I$(ALE)/src/os_dependent -I$(ALE)/src/environment -I$(ALE)/src/external -L$(ALE) -L../Caffe/caffe/build/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
 CXX := g++ -std=c++11
 INC:= GAImage.cpp GAScreen.cpp GABrain.cpp
 FILE := main 
 LDFLAGS := -lale -lz -lpthread -lglog -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lcblas -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lcudnn -lcaffe
```

The program compiles succesfully but when I try to run the result I get the following error:

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libcaffe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But the file is clearly at the location: ../Caffe/caffe/build/lib which I have included. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you link, it includes a little note in the executable to the dynamic linker that “hey, I need `libcaffe.so`!” but it doesn’t say where to find it. When you run the program, you may need to give the dynamic linker some extra information, saying “hey, when you’re looking for libraries, check here too!”, and you can do by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to the directory containing `libcaffe.so` before running your program.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Don't bother I found it. For me this worked: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/guinness/GamerIA/Caffe/caffe/build/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}. Thank you so so much for the help!